# customize redirection logged in user on /login route - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have a laravel application

login page is in route /login

there is a logged in user and clicks on a login button (or basically open URL /login)

application redirects the user to /home but I want to be redirected to /dashboard

I changed the redirect fields in Auth controllers to /dashboard. results when a user signs in, application redirects him to /dashboard
but what about a logged in user?

I use laravel 5.4, thank you for helping

Comment: You can use `protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware that is supplied with Laravel located in `App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated`.

Then, in the following block, make sure it's set to `/dashboard`.

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    return redirect('/dashboard');
}
```

Then add the middleware to your login route by either wrapping it in a group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function(){
    //Auth routes for non-authenticated users
});
```

Or you can do it on the route directly:

```
->middleware('guest');
```

Comment: tnx. that wrong redirection was in this middle-ware. after fixing that, every thing worked fine

Answer (score 1):

Goto login controller which is located in

```
app->Http->Auth->LoginController
```

Set

```
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard'
```

Hope it works.

Source : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#included-authenticating

Comment: I've done this. it works when you login not when you are logged in and open  URL /login

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to redirect logged in user you can override `showLoginForm()` method in `LoginController` like this:

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    if (auth()->check()) {
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }

    return view('auth.login');
}
```

But I guess a better way to solve the problem could be just hiding login button or link from logged in users:

```
@if (auth()->guest())
    {{-- Show register and login links --}}
@endif
```